# Is the WSO2IS administrator also locked when the password expires

Tags: locking, wso2-identity-server

With setting the parameters `Identity.Listener.Enable` and `Notification.Expire.Time` in file `identity-­mgt.properties` of WSO2IS the expire time of all users passwords are set. An user will be locked if the password passes this expire time. The user can be unlocked with the admin user of a tenant.

So, also the admin user can be lockef if the password expires. Nor the password of the admin nor the password of other locked users can be unlocked anymore.  Or, does the setting `Notification.Expire.Time` not affect the Admin user at all, and the Admin is never locked on this parameter?

In case the Admin can also be locked, which feature does WSO2IS offer for unlocking the admin user of a tenant?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to lock admin user or tenant admin users. You can configure above settings mentioned in question, but it doesn't affect the admin users.